# I want to remove Ubuntu and Windows from a USB stick

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu and install Windows. I created a bootable USB stick and a bootable CD of Windows. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I install my CD or bootable disk and try to boot from USB disk or CD drive, Ubuntu doesn't do that. It directly loads Ubuntu. I created an Ubuntu live USB stick so that I can create a partition using GParted. But I can’t load it as I can’t boot from CD or pen drive.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the USB/CD is bootable, and your BIOS is configured to try and boot from the USB/CD drive first, you should be able to boot into the Windows installer.

Make sure to set the boot priority in the BIOS.

[Directions for USB Windows install.](http://www.howtogeek.com/191054/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drives-and-sd-cards-for-every-operating-system/)

[How to change your boot device & boot order](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/)

Comment: USB booting can be done from legacy BIOSes, but the boot-order needs to be set. Maybe explain quickly how to set the boot order? Otherwise, +1